# Add {NavLink} to React Component Showing Blank Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm new to React.js and already make new react app using :

> create-react-app

I already install dependency

> react-router-dom

```
var React = require('react');
var NavLink = require('react-router-dom').NavLink;
```

The problem is when I add NavLink to my component, it will show blank page :

Before :

```
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a>Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Result : [It Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkqxT.png)

But when I add the navlink

After :

```
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/menu1">Menu 1</NavLink></li>
          <li><a>Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
```

It became blank pages : [Showing Blank Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eHur.png)

How to fix it ?

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: There should be errors in your code. Did you check your console log to find out ?

Comment: Thankyou , I check console on chrome and found error at Router, then the solution:

At my App.js , I should add Navbar to <Router> and make them into one <div>

Comment: You most likely won't get an error when you're in production. Switch back to development and test for errors on that route. Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

use  around your App.js

like in index.js first import

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>      
   <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```